# texto sobrepondo o before

Tags: css, css3

```css
li#tel::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="tel">Telefone</li>
</ul>
```

Estou fazendo um **before** da forma acima e estou tendo os seguintes problemas:

Como o **position** é **absolute**, a imagem está *sobrepondo* ao **texto** da **li** no **before**.
Se eu tiro o **position** ou seto ele para **relative**, o **before** não aparece.

O que fazer?

Comment: Consegue fazer um [mcve] demonstrando?

Comment: sim, alterado na pergunta

Comment: E como seria esperado ficar?

Comment: a imagem (before) com 50px e logo após o texto

Comment: desculpe Anderson, o texto após a imagem!

Comment: minha dificuldade está em fazer a imagem aparecer

Comment: Ah, eu li "é logo após" hehe

Comment: antes usando ::before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por padrão, o elemento `before` possui `display: inline`, o que fará que será exibido antes do texto, como o esperado, porém sem respeitar as dimensões dadas. Um elemento `inline` sempre respeitará o seu conteúdo, não as propriedades `width` e `height`.

Para fazer com que seja respeitado as dimensões, basta alterar para `display: inline-block`.

```css
li#tel::before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    background: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="tel">Telefone</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Entendi. Mas como fazer para que o texto e a imagem estejam na mesma linha? Tipo vertical-align: midlle?

Answer (score 3):

Não sei realmente se existe uma forma da maneira que quer fazer, *pode ser que alguém mais tarde de uma outra resposta melhor*, mas, se entendi bem se o que quer é inserir a imagem antes do texto, pode usar uma tag **`span`** no texto e fazer o que quiser com ela, inclusive adicionar uma **margin** ou um **padding**:

```css
li#tel::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
span {
    padding-left: 55px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="tel"><span>Telefone</span></li>
</ul>
```